# How I can make tmux not create a infinite loop of "tmuxes"?

Tags: linux, loops, tmux, archlinux, xonsh

So, I'm using Xonsh Shell and tmux, where on `~/.xonshrc`, the contents are this:

```
# XONSH WEBCONFIG START
$XONSH_COLOR_STYLE = 'rainbow_dash'
# XONSH WEBCONFIG END
$XONSH_SHOW_TRACEBACK = True
$all_proxy="socks5://localhost:9050"
$UPDATE_OS_ENVIRON = True
tmux
xdotool key ctrl+b c
xdotool key ctrl+b 0
xdotool type "weechat"
```

Is there a way I can make tmux NOT start any more instances of itself?

I tried to unset TMUX enviroment variable, hoping that this would not happen anymore, but it just created more instances this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is how the infinite loop happens —

1. You start `xonsh`
2. `xonsh` loads `.xonshrc`
3. `.xonshrc` starts `tmux` or create new `tmux` windows
4. In new `tmux` windows, `tmux` starts new `xonsh`
5. Go to step 2.

You can try like this:

```
if not !(tmux ls):
    tmux new -d
    tmux new-window
    tmux send -t :0 weechat enter
    tmux attach -t :0
```